# Modman - 500 error after module installation - how to fix it?

Tags: magento-1.9, error, modman, http-error-500

After module installation Server error 500.
Is there any way to check what is causing this issue ?
How to restore to the state before installation ?
Tried modman repair, no success, tried remove module manually, repair, still no luck, any ideas ?

Comment: Clear db data if any for that module

Comment: Checked core_resource, nothing  there.

Comment: a 500 error should leave extra information in the server's error log. As you mentioned it's no /var/log/apache2/error.log so you would need to keep looking. Is it even using apache2? Does it have separate log files per virtual host? Does it maybe have a separate error log for php-fpm?

Comment: Found it, sorted it, works :)